# Bootstrap Everything is in Navbar

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

im currently trying to do a Website with Bootstrap, but everything after my Navbar is being put in my Navbar like the Div Container with id "main" here.

its my first time trying to do Styling with Bootstrap I tripple checked if I closed every html Tag but maybe you find something.

anyone can help me?

```
class AppView {
    public function showTemplateHead() {

        $ausgabe = '<!DOCTYPE html>'.
                        '<html>'.
                            '<head>'.
                                '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">'.
                                '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'.
                                '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'.
                                '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'.
                                '<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>'.
                                '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">'.
                                '<title>Valorant Line-Ups</title>'.
                        
                            '</head>'.
                            '<body>';
                            $ausgabe .= $this->showNavbar();
                            $ausgabe .= '<div id="main">';
                            
        return $ausgabe;
    }
    public function showTemplateFooter() {
        $ausgabe = '        </div>
                        </body>
                    </html>';
                return $ausgabe;
    }

    public function showNavbar()  {
        $ausgabe = ''.
            '<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">'.
                '<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Valorant Line-ups</a>'.
                '<div class="dropdown">'.
                    '<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">'.
                    'Choose Map'.
                    '</button>'.
                    '<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">';

    
                    foreach (array_diff(scandir("img/maps"), array('..', '.')) as $map) {
                        $ausgabe .= "<li data-id='$map'><a class='dropdown-item dropMap'>".substr($map, 0, -4)."</a></li>";
                    }
                    '</ul>'.
                '</div>'.
            '</nav>';
            return $ausgabe;
    }

}
```

Edit:

This is where im displaying it all:

```
<?php 

/**
 * Die Klasse AppcController steuert den Ablauf und reagiert auf das Verhalten des Users
 * @author Sascha Belau
 */

class AppController {
    private $data;
    private $output = '';
    private $action = '';


    /**
     * Erstellt ein neues Objekt der Klasse Appcontroller
     * @param array $data Gesammelte GET-, POST- & SESSION-Daten
     */
    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $model = new AppModel();

        $this->init($data);
    }
    public function init($data) {
        if(isset($data['action'])) {
            $action = $data['action'];
        } else {
            $action = '';
        }

        $view = new AppView();
        $model = new AppModel();


        switch ($action) {
            default:
                echo $view->showTemplateHead();
                echo $view->showTemplateFooter();
                break;
            case 'chooseMap':
                echo "Hello";
                break;
        }

    }
}



?>
```

Edit: Result [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXM4L.png)
and as you can see the Div is inside of the

Edit: Still the same so not Chrome I guess.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Valorant Line-Ups</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Valorant Line-ups</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Choose Map</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li data-id='Ascent.png'><a class='dropdown-item dropMap'>Ascent</a></li>
        <li data-id='Bind.png'><a class='dropdown-item dropMap'>Bind</a></li>
        <li data-id='Breeze.png'><a class='dropdown-item dropMap'>Breeze</a></li>
        <li data-id='Fracture.png'><a class='dropdown-item dropMap'>Fracture</a></li>
        <li data-id='Haven.png'><a class='dropdown-item dropMap'>Haven</a></li>
        <li data-id='Icebox.png'><a class='dropdown-item dropMap'>Icebox</a></li>
        <li data-id='Split.png'><a class='dropdown-item dropMap'>Split</a></li>
        <div id="main">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us where you are "glueing" this altogether to render your page?

Comment: Just edited my Post

Comment: Sorry can you update your answer to show what your actual rendered HTML as a result of this looks like?

Comment: Edited it just now

Comment: Are you sure you are giving us all the relevant parts of your code. What you have provided in PHP definitely does not match up with the HTML you are showing like you mentioned. Could there be some Javascript or caching in play perhaps?

Comment: Nah its exactly what you see, in the first Code Snippet you have the View with the Header information and all the Navbar rendering with Bootstrap and the Footer with just closing the HTML tags. I have a JavaScript in there buts its just an Empty file yet

Comment: It just looks like i didnt close a <ul> right but i tripple checked they are all Closed. I do not know why my <div> is inside of the <ul>

Comment: Very bizarre. Can you right click on the page in your browser and then choose "View Page Source" and see what that looks like perhaps it is different. I have seen from time to time in Chrome Dev Tools that the "Elements" tab can get confused and try to fix itself in some situations.

Comment: I just Found whats wrong I didnt append the closing </ul> with another "$ausgabe .=  "

Comment: Alright - curious - was it my View Page Source suggestion that helped you?

Comment: Yeah it helped so that I could see a good Breakdown of the HTML code